# adobe illustrator cannot export text elements with multiple lines to svg

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, svg, export

I am using Adobe Illustrator to generate SVG files. However, I find that when I try to export a textual element with multiple lines, that element is exported as svg paths, not svg text elements. If the textual element DOES contain a single line, the export works as expected.

[image: multi line example]

This Adobe Illustrator text element has multiple lines. It is exported into svg `path` elements. Example:

```
<g id="dupe_MFG_PKG:_12.13.21_BATCH:_210001392_UID:_1A4060300002EE1000024872" data-name="dupe MFG/PKG: 12.13.21 | BATCH: 210001392UID: 1A4060300002EE1000024872">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M.29.9h.4L1.34,3,2,.9h.4V5.1H2.05V1.78L1.35,4h0l-.7-2.2V5.1H.29Z" transform="translate(-0.29 -0.49)"/>
    ....
```

[image: single line example]

This Adobe Illustrator text element has a single line. It is exported into svg `text` elements. Example:

```
<g id="Layer_26" data-name="Layer 26">
          <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(0 10.3) scale(1 1.01)"><tspan class="cls-2">L</tspan><tspan x="3.34" y="0">o</tspan><tspan class="cls-3" x="7.73" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-4" x="10.38" y="0">em ipsum</tspan></text>
    ...
```

I need the export to preserve all text. What can be done to achieve this? I'd prefer not to enforce constraints on the designer ("Please make sure each text element is a single line") but I'm otherwise forced to "break up" the design doc OR manually recreate the svg by hand.

Comment: Has the text in the fist example been altered? Transformed? Appearance changed in any way? Does it interact with other objects with appearance alterations?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By experimentation, I was able to find the culprit: improper control characters. I used this tool: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php and found the `0x03` or ctrl+C where a `cr lf` characters ought to have been. The solution is very simple- from Adobe, backspace over the incorrect invisible `0x03` white-space and then hit return to replace it with the correct characters.

Comment: While I've never hit this issue specifically, for *years* I've been asking Adobe to fix the random whitespace character at the end of multi-line text in *all* their applications. It will also throw off centering at times (more prominently in InDesign).